# Pop Up doesn't close when I click anywhere outside the Pop Up if the Pop Up is opened using MouseUp event of any other control

Tags: wpf, popup

I have a pop up in my application whose StaysOpen property is set to false . This pop is opened on MouseUp event of a Image  as below

If I opens the Pop up on "MouseDown" event of Image then it gets closed close when I click anywhere outside the PopUp , Don't know why ?? Any suggestions

Thanks
Kapil

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the pop-up is closing? If you click on your main application (i.e. outside your pop-up) it will pull the application view to the front and push the pop-up behind it. It would appear that your pop-up had closed but if you minimize your application you might find your pop-up hidden behind it.